# How I can ask to open a type of file everytime?

Tags: android, pdf, mime-types, intentfilter

I'm trying to do an activity to save certain PDF that the user can find over internet. I'm blocked in with the next code.

```
<activity
            android:name=".pdf.OpenPDFActivity"
            android:label="Add to Notapp"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I want to be asked to open a PDF file with my app, and other viewers. My app will store the file, so I want that every time a user click on a PDF the dialog shows my app and the viewers, but the dialog has a button to remember the choosen app. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Which application downloads the PDF file? If it is a self-written app you can implement your own chooser dialog, otherwise you can only use the system chooser dialog you have described.

Comment: The pdfs are external, from the chrome, for example. So, the download is from the system.

Comment: `every time a user click on a PDF`. You forgot to tell where/when/how the user does such a thing. In what kind of app?

Comment: When a user click in any pdf, downloading from the internet or inside de memory. The choosen dialog ask for always remember the selection or just once. I want that with the PDF files, the button "always" dissapear, or the file association will be deleted if the user click on always. So everytime a user open a PDF, the dialog appears.

Comment: `When a user click in any pdf, downloading from the internet or inside de memory.` Sorry but that is not much to the point. I have no idea where the user clicks on and in which app. You should start with that.

Comment: The "application/pdf" data works for me on Android 4.4.2 but not on 5.0. What are you using?

Comment: For the rest and rereading your post it's unclear to me with what you have problems. Don't your intent filters work? Or has the user once choosen one app to handle pdf's and that was not yours so the user never has to choose an app to handle pdf's any more. Please explain.

Comment: If you had installed my application. When you open a PDF file, you should see a selection dialog to choose the application to open the PDF. That dialogue shows two buttons, "always" and "just once". What I ask is whether there is any way that the "always" button is not displayed. What I look for is that the user's choice is not remembered.